# Force ffap to ignore '<' and '>' in file names

Tags: find-file, ffap

I am using find-file-at-point and it stubbornly selects incorrect file name string in NXML mode:

String where I have cursor on the file name:

```
<include>my-file.ext</include>
```

and when evaluating: `(ffap-string-at-point)` it selects "`>my-file.ext</include`".

Is there some simple way to tell ffap that '<' and '>' are NOT part of the file name?

Thanks, this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is based on `ffap-string-at-point-mode-alist`. Take a look at the current value and doc string.

You'll see an entry like this:

```
(file "--:\\\\${}+<>@-Z_[:alpha:]~*?" "<@" "@>;.,!:")
```

The format here is (MODE CHARS BEG END) where CHARS are characters to include and BEG and END are characters to drop from the beginning and end. Notice that `<` and `>` are included as valid characters but also dropped at the beginning/end, which is why you're getting the seemingly odd match `>my-file.ext</include`.

One possible fix: add a new entry for XML files that does not include `<>` in the set of valid chars:

```
(add-to-list 'ffap-string-at-point-mode-alist
         '(nxml-mode "--:\\\\${}+@-Z_[:alpha:]~*?" "<@" "@>;.,!:"))
```

Comment: You are my hero for today! That was it! If I had more reputation points I would vote you up visibly! I hope somebody else will.